# reformatting a Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame with the following format:

```
Id    Term    weight
t1    frack   0.733
t1    shale   0.700
t10   space   0.645
t10   station 0.327
t10   nasa    0.258
t4    celebr  0.262
t4    bahar   0.345
t4    frack   1.2
t5    shale   0.8
t5    nasa    0.1
```

I need reformat it as following:

```
Term    t1       t10       t4      t5
frack   0.733
 shale   0.700
space             0.645
station           0.327
 nasa              0.258
 celebr                    0.262
 bahar                     0.345
 frack                       1.2
 shale                              0.8
 nasa                               0.1
```

How I can do it?

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index='Term', columns='Id', values='weight')`

Comment: or `pd.crosstab(df.Term,columns=df.Id,values=df.weight,aggfunc='sum').fillna('')`